# Deploy Azure cloud service with HTTPS

Tags: azure

I published a website hosted by Azure cloud service. Currently, the website can be accessed by HTTP protocol.

Does Windows Azure cloud service support HTTPS protocol? Is that possible to secure it with SSL? What are the steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the Following article that shows how to configure SSL for a Cloud service.
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate/

-Nithin